# How to get the value of a textarea with Jquery on enter key press while jquery elastic is enabled

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a comment system like Facebook and I am trying to stop it from appending when the comment field is empty. My comment system is working with [Jquery Elastic](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/) that enables the textarea to be expanded when someone is typing or when I press Enter and Shift.

**Problem**

I do not want the form to append when the textarea is empty but it does in spite of my verification and it is unable to tell when the textarea is empty

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $('#comment').keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){
          var comment = $('textarea#comment').val();
          var sid = $('#sid').val();
          if(comment == "")
          {
              alert("Please write something in comment."); 
          }
          else
          {
              $("#commentbox").append("<div class='commentarea'>"+comment+"</div>");
              $.post("index.php", {sid:sid,comment:comment},function(data)
              {                                                             
              })
              $('#comment').val("");
          }
        }
    });
 });
</script>
<style>
.status
{
    width:350px;
    max-width:100%;

    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
.commentarea
{
    width:350px;
    max-width:100%;

    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    border: thin;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 96%);
    padding: 5px;
}
#comment
{
    width: 357px;
    max-width:100%;

    height: 23px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
</style>


<script src="js/jquery_elastic_1_6_11/jquery.elastic.source.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[
            //jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){          
                jQuery('textarea').elastic();
                jQuery('textarea').trigger('update');
            }); 
            // ]]>
  </script>            
  <link href="js/jquery_elastic_1_6_11/dependencies/screen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />   
<div class="status"> <?php echo $status; ?></div>
<div id="commentbox">
 <?php echo $commentshow; ?> 
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
<textarea  name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write a comment...."></textarea>
```

**How to determine when the textarea is empty and stop it from appending ?**

NOTE: I have also tried `var comment= $('textarea#comment').val();` but still ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this problem is when the user presses the ENTER key, the value of the textbox contains a newline whitespace. Thus, the value of the textbox is not an empty string. You can call trim() on the comment value to get rid of any leading or trailing whitespace.

```
var comment = $('textarea#comment').val().trim();
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ytnLL1g/).